# Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::getSkipper()

Tags: php, class, methods, undefined

I'm trying to teach myself OOP in PHP. I have an error from a child class, does anybody know why I would be getting this error?

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method User::getSkipper() in C:\wamp\www\starter\display.php on line 28

The User class is this:

```
<?php
class User
{
    protected $_first_name;
    protected $_last_name;
    protected $_email;

    public function __construct($first_name, $last_name, $email) 
    {
        $this->_first_name = $first_name;
        $this->_last_name = $last_name;
        $this->_email = $email;
    }

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->_first_name;
    }

    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->_last_name;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->_email;
    }       
}

?>
```

The Skipper class is this:

```
<?php
class Skipper extends User
{
    protected $_skipper;

    public function __construct($first_name, $last_name, $email, $skipper) 
    {
        $this->_skipper = $skipper;
    }

    public function getSkipper()
    {
        return $this->_skipper;
    }
}
?>
```

The error is thrown when executing the following code:

```
$user1 = new User('Steven', 'Smith', 'steve@sljgksdj.com', 'Yes');
echo '<p>First Name: ' . $user1->getFirstName() .'</p>';
echo '<p>Last Name: ' . $user1->getLastName() .'</p>';
echo '<p>Email: ' . $user1->getEmail() .'</p>';
echo '<p>Skipper: ' . $user1->getSkipper() .'</p>';
```

Comment: add skıpper varıable to your construct functıon of User

Comment: You are calling skipper method with object of user class while extending user to skipper.instantiate skipper.or pass the object to user's constructor

Answer (score 0):

If skipper extends User, you need instantiate Skipper.  Also, I'm confused as to what you are trying to achieve with passing 'Yes" into the Skipper constructor.

```
<?php
class User
{
    protected $_first_name;
    protected $_last_name;
    protected $_email;

    public function __construct($first_name, $last_name, $email) 
    {
    $this->_first_name = $first_name;
    $this->_last_name = $last_name;
    $this->_email = $email;
   }

   public function getFirstName()
   {
    return $this->_first_name;
    }

    public function getLastName()
   {
    return $this->_last_name;
    }

    public function getEmail()
   {
    return $this->_email;
    }       
};

<?php
class Skipper extends User
{
protected $_skipper;

    public function __construct($first_name, $last_name, $email, $skipper) 
   {
    parent::__construct($first_name, $last_name, $email) 
    $this->_skipper = $skipper;
    }

    public function getSkipper()
    {
    return $this->_skipper;
    }
}

$skipper1 = new Skipper('Steven', 'Smith', 'steve@sljgksdj.com', 'Yes');
echo '<p>First Name: ' . $skipper1->getFirstName() .'</p>';
echo '<p>Last Name: ' . $skipper1->getLastName() .'</p>';
echo '<p>Email: ' . $skipper1->getEmail() .'</p>';
```

Comment: Ok thanks calling the skipper class worked. I did have to add require once to the file that contains skipper.

Comment: I wanted to define if they were a skipper not just a user

Comment: Then you can use "$var instanceof Skipper"

Answer (score 0):

You create an Object of class `user` and User soes not have any method `getSkipper`.
You should create a object of class `Skipper`.

```
$user1 = new Skipper('Steven', 'Smith', 'steve@sljgksdj.com', 'Yes');
```

Comment: @ChristopherPecoraro Yes You need them to set the `_skipper`variable. And you have to call `parent::__construct($first_name, $last_name, $email)` to initialize the other tree variables.

Comment: Why do they need to set _skipper if the object is already of type Skipper?  Couldn't they just use instanceof()?